# How to accelerate translation animation in LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx, interpolation

Is it possible to increase velocity dynamically for Actor in LibGDX? e.g. move actor from point A to point B with pre-defined time but dynamically and linearly increasing it's velocity?
I couldn't find any good LibGDX interpolation for that purpose

Comment: `Interpolation.pow2in` or `pow3in`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The [Universal Tween Engine](http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/) may be what you want, if it's just for a visual effect.

If it's for a game object though, like a rocket or something, then either increase the velocity a little bit each frame, or (better) use Box2D which is built into libgdx.